# How to resolve Overload resolution ambiguity for context.report within custom lint rules?

Tags: android, kotlin, static-analysis, lint

I started learning how to make a few basic lint rules today, trying to create a lint rule for variables, to check the length of their names.

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
class VariableLengthDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {

override fun getApplicableUastTypes() = listOf(UVariable::class.java)

override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) =
    VariableLengthHandler(context)


class VariableLengthHandler(private val context: JavaContext) :
    UElementHandler() {

    private val variableMinimumLength = 3

    override fun visitVariable(node: UVariable) {

        node.name?.let {
            if (it.length < variableMinimumLength) {
                context.report(
                    issue = variableLengthIssue,
                    scope = node,
                    location = context.getNameLocation(node),
                    message = "this variable can be better named"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

this code doesn't compile, because of overload ambiguity caused here:

```
context.report(issue = variableLengthIssue,
               scope = node,
               location = context.getNameLocation(node),
               message = "this variable can be better named")
```

from what I can understand, it's caused because the overloads for context.report can either be

```
public final fun report(issue: Issue, scope: PsiElement?,...
```

or it can be

```
public final fun report(issue: Issue, scope: UElement?,...
```

but I'm not sure how to define these using the Uvariable element that I have?

How do I resolve this overload ambiguity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it as `UElement`.

```kotlin
context.report(
    issue = variableLengthIssue,
    scope = node as UElement,
    location = context.getNameLocation(node),
    message = "this variable can be better named"
)
```